# Redux form and Typescript wants me to add all props from InjectedFormProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I have a little problem with redux form and typescript, I have a form component that I'm using with multiple components, and when I add typings and I declare the form in another component TS wants me to add all missing props that are present in InjectedFormProps.

## My Form

```
type IProps = {
  tournee: boolean,
  twentytwo?: number,
  eighteen?: number,
  fourteen?: number,
  nine?: number,
  twentyfour?: number,
  argent?: number,
  onSubmit: (formValues: IGold) => void;
};

type TGoldForm = InjectedFormProps<IGold, IProps> & IProps;

const defaultProps = {
  twentytwo: 0,
  eighteen: 0,
  fourteen: 0,
  nine: 0,
  twentyfour: 0,
  argent: 0,
};

function dateWithMonthsDelay(months) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + months);
  return date;
}

const GoldForm = ({
  change, handleSubmit, onSubmit,
  tournee, twentytwo, eighteen,
  fourteen, nine, argent, twentyfour,
}: TGoldForm) => {

}

GoldForm.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const redForm = reduxForm<IGold, TGoldForm>({
  form: 'gold',
  validate,
})(GoldForm);

export default redForm;
```

## IGold typing

```
export interface IGold {
  _id: string,
  twentyfour: number,
  twentytwo: number,
  eighteen: number,
  fourteen: number,
  nine: number,
  argent: number,
  store: string,
  user: string | IUser,
  tournee: Date,
  createdAt: Date,
}
```

Component that I Add GoldForm

```
const EditGold = ({
  match,
}:RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onSubmit = (formValues: IGold) => {
    dispatch(editGold({ id: match.params.id, formValues }));
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOneGold(match.params.id));
    return () => {
      dispatch(cleanOneGold());
    };
  }, []);
  const gold = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.gold.oneBuys);
  const auth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.gold.oneBuysLoading);
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? <p>Loading</p> : (
        <GoldForm
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          tournee={false}
          twentyfour={gold?.twentyfour}
          twentytwo={gold?.twentytwo}
          eighteen={gold?.eighteen}
          fourteen={gold?.fourteen}
          nine={gold?.nine}
          argent={gold?.argent}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default EditGold;
```

## Error

Typescript wants me to add all the functions from InjectedFormProps to Props

```
Type '{ onSubmit: (formValues: IGold) => void; tournee: false; twentyfour: number | undefined; twentytwo: number | undefined; eighteen: number | undefined; fourteen: number | undefined; nine: number | undefined; argent: number | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<DecoratedFormProps<IGold, TGoldForm, string>>': anyTouched, array, asyncValidate, asyncValidating, and 23 more.ts(2740)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this.

```
type IProps = {
  tournee: boolean,
  twentytwo?: number,
  eighteen?: number,
  fourteen?: number,
  nine?: number,
  twentyfour?: number,
  argent?: number,
  onSubmit: (formValues: IGold) => void;
};

type TGoldForm = InjectedFormProps<IGold, IProps> & IProps;

const defaultProps = {
  twentytwo: 0,
  eighteen: 0,
  fourteen: 0,
  nine: 0,
  twentyfour: 0,
  argent: 0,
};

function dateWithMonthsDelay(months) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + months);
  return date;
}

const GoldForm = ({
  change, handleSubmit, onSubmit,
  tournee, twentytwo, eighteen,
  fourteen, nine, argent, twentyfour,
}: TGoldForm) => {

}

GoldForm.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const redForm = reduxForm<IGold, IProps>({
  form: 'gold',
  validate,
})(GoldForm);

export default redForm;
```